# "there is some milk" or "there are some milk"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, existentials

> There is some milk

Or

> There are some milk

Which sentence is more correct according to the grammar rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use “there is” for singular nouns and for uncountable nouns, and we use “there are” for plural countable nouns.

"There is some milk" is correct.

Comment: Yes. No matter how "big" the uncountable quantity. "There IS a lot of trash in this room." Indeed, "There IS an infinite amount of ignorance in the world."